# org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader cannot be resolved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

i am unable to import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader. it shows the following error.

**My error:**

[image]

**My Pom File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc.springbatch.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBatch</name>
    <description>Spring Batch</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.poi.PoiItemReader cannot be resolved. i clearly mentioned required dependencies in my pom file.

do i need to add any other dependency?

Answer (score 1):

No, You don't need other dependencies. 
The issue is that **spring-batch-excel** is not present in remote maven repository. So you need to install it manually in your local maven cache.

To do that:

**1. Check out the sources of spring batch extenstion**

```
git clone git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions.git
```

**2. Go into the directory of a spring-batch-excel module**

```
cd spring-batch-extensions

cd spring-batch-excel
```

**3. Compile and test, build all jars**

```
mvn clean package
```

**4. Install the modules jars into your local Maven cache**

```
mvn install
```

Now **spring-batch-excel** is present in your local maven cache.

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You need the spring batch extention for excel. refer to [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/master/spring-batch-excel)

Comment: do you add dependency?

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: solved this issue. between thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-excel</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Above dependency is correct for Excel PoiItemReader.

Comment: the dependency that you mentioned did not work for me. but the one I have mentioned worked for me.

Comment: @karthickS : Looks like you have some dependency management prblem which might causing this. However you can see this dependencies on maven official site :https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch.extensions/spring-batch-excel/0.1.0 . The one which you have mentioned is not official rather a personal .